# PHP If folder exists do a loop for each subfolder

Tags: php, while-loop

I am trying to get my code to work. I basically check that if a folder exists, and any sub folder exists within that directory called 3 or more (3,4,5) then do a loop, otherwise nothing.

```
// the folder path
$folderPath="".cdnurl."assets/".pid."";
// looks like site.com/assets/342/

// is there a sub folder called 3 or more, 3,4,5 and loop from 3
// site.com/assets/342/3
// site.com/assets/342/4
// etc, we only loop if 3 exists other wise nothing

$folderSubNumber =>3;

    while(file_exists($folderPath.$folderSubNumber)) {

        echo '<li><img src="assets/pid/'.folderSubNumber.'';

    } else {

    // nothing 
        echo "";    
    }
```

Comment: PHP doesn't have while(){} else {} statements, try removing the else {} and see what happens.

Comment: There is no such thing as `while(){} else{}`, `folderSubNumber` needs a `$` in the `echo` line, and `$folderSubNumber =>3;` should be `$folderSubNumber = 3;` (`=>` is only for array keys/values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Build folder path
$folder_path = cdnurl . 'assets/' . $pid . '/';

// Loop from 3 to 5
for ($i = 3; i <= 5; $i++) {

  // Checking for a valid sub-directory
  // Will check sub-directory e.g.: site.com/assets/342/3/
  if ( is_dir($folder_path . $i . '/') ) {

    // Sub-directory exists
    echo $folder_path . $i;
  } else {

    // No Sub-directory, break out of for loop
    // This is will stop PHP for looking for sub-directory 4 or 5
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like what you have should do it. Just change that `=>` to a simple `=`, and don't forget to increment:

```
while (file_exists($folderPath.$folderSubNumber)) {
    echo '...';
    $folderSubNumber += 1;
}
```

(Also, the `else` part isn't allowed. But you don't need it here, so nothing lost.)

Comment: Forgot about the file separator mentioned by @Helgi: that should be `$folderPath.'/'.$folderSubNumber`

Answer (score 2):

A simple method:

```
$subdirs = glob(cdnurl . "assets/" . pid . "/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

that'll return all subdirectories in the specified directory. Ref: http://php.net/glob

Comment: But that doesn't really help with only the subdirectories that are named "3" or higher.

Comment: It's a unix-shell style pattern matching. If you want files that start with 3,4,5,6,7,8,9, then do `yadayada/[3456789]*` for the glob pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare for some constructive criticism, please.

There's a lot wrong with this code. First I'll add comments to explain some of the mistakes as well as some of the pointless things that do nothing.

```
$folderPath="".cdnurl."assets/".pid."";
// 1. Single-quotes will perform slightly better.
// 2. There is no need for the first "". or the final ."" - they do nothing.
// 3. Ideal: $folderPath = cdnurl.'assets/'.pid;
// 4. This assumes that cdnurl and pid are constants declared with the define() command. If they are not constants, you need dollar-signs, which would make it:
//    $folderPath = $cdnurl.'assets/'.$pid;

$folderSubNumber => 3;
// You cannot put a "more than X" or "less than X" in a variable. The => is used in foreach() loops for a completely different purpose, and when declaring values in an array only when the array is originally declared. (In other words; in this case, this does nothing.)

// Indentation really does matter. This should be indented the same as the code above.
while(file_exists($folderPath.$folderSubNumber)) {
    // 1. $folderSubNumber never changes and so this while-loop always asks the exact same question.
    // 2. You don't have a directory separator "/", so this will append $folderSubNumber straight to pid, above.

    echo '<li><img src="assets/pid/'.folderSubNumber.'';
    // 1. folderSubNumber needs a dollar-sign because it's a variable. If it is not defined as a constant, it will simply be the literal string "folderSubNumber".
    // 2. The appended .'' does nothing and shouldn't be there.
    // 3. You are neither closing the <img> tag, nor the <li> tag, nor in fact the src-attribute.
    // 4. Ideal: echo '<li><img src="assets/pid/'.$folderSubNumber.'" /></li>';

} else {
    // 1. There is no "else" in while.
    // 2. You don't need an "else" if the intention is to do nothing.

    echo "";
    // This is 100% pointless, it does nothing.
}
```

What you then need, is to increment $foldeSubNumber after you've tried it in the while-loop (see the answer by 'sdleihssirhc'). But also note that you probably need the directory separator between $folderPath and $folderSubNumber. That would be: `$folderPath.'/'.$folderSubNumber`

Good luck!